# Update same frame for videoeffect during PauseMode ( MediaElement AddVideoEffect XAML UWP )

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-10-universal, mediaelement, uwp-xaml

I am working on an UWP app. Using the XAML MediaElement class and AddVideoEffect method, I am able to apply the corresponding videoeffects 
while the "play" is on.  Apparently, when the "Play" is on, it applies the video effect to the next frame but when the player is in "Pause" mode, there is no effect being taken.

I would like to know if there is a way to apply the videoeffects to the same frame during "Pause" mode.

Please help!

Here is my Code Snippet :

```
            using Windows.UI.Xaml;
            using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;


            MediaElement mElement;
            mElement.Source(input);
            mElement.AddVideoEffect("videoeffect", true, IPropertySet );
            mElement.Play(); //Effect takes place only when video is in play.No VideoEffect when the MediaElement is in Pause Mode.
```

Comment: Could you please upload a minimal reproduced project?